# How does mysql deal with queries that touches myisam and innodb tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, join

In our mysql database, we use both myisam and innodb tables, though there are more myisam tables.

## QUESTIONS

- If a query involves both myisam and innodb tables, will the query use table lock or row lock on innodb tables?
- Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 3):

There are three aspects to doing a JOIN query that is can be alarming

## ASPECT #1 : Locking Behavior

Whenever there are joins involving MyISAM and InnoDB, InnoDB tables will end up behaving like MyISAM in terms of table-level locking instead of its normal row-level locking.[**MVCC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) and [**ACID compliance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) cannot be applied to the MyISAM data. It could possibly be stagnated for InnoDB tables as well.

## ASPECT #2 : MyISAM's Involvement

If any MyISAM table is being updated via INSERTs, UPDATEs, or DELETEs, the MyISAM table involved in a JOIN query would be locked from other DB Connections, forcing the JOIN query to wait until the MyISAM table can be read. In light of this, if there is a mix of InnoDB and MyISAM in a JOIN query, the InnoDB tables would be subject to intermittent locking of PRIMARY KEY entries (in the Clustered Index).

Keep in mind that [MVCC will still allow `READ-UNCOMMITTED` and `REPEATABLE-READ` transactions to work just fine and let certain views of data be available for other transactions. The same cannot be said for READ-COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939790/491757).

## ASPECT #3 : Query Optimizer's View of the JOIN

### MyISAM

MySQL will rely on the index cardinality of tables to determine an optimized EXPLAIN plan. Index cardinality is usually stable for a MyISAM table until it is inundated with INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs. Consequently, you will needs to periodically run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` against the MyISAM table.

### InnoDB

InnoDB's index cardinality is NEVER STABLE !!! If you run `SHOW INDEXES FROM innodbtable;`, you will see the index cardinality change each time you run that command. That's because InnoDB will do dives into the index to estimate the cardinality. Even if you run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` against an InnoDB table, that will only defragment the table. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will run `ANALYZE TABLE` internally to generate index statistics against the table. That works for MyISAM. InnoDB would usually ignore it. You could disable [**innodb_stats_on_metadata**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata) to get stable EXPLAIN plans, but that would just cause you to do ANALYZE TABLE maintenance on InnoDB tables as much as you would a MyISAM table.

## EPILOGUE

Believe it or not, there is [**still an open ticket on InnoDB/MyISAM joining during a SELECT FOR UPDATE**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57118). If you read it, it sums up the resolution as follows : **DON'T DO JOINs THAT MIX InnoDB and MyISAM, please**.