# Why isn't the rows of an EXPLAIN accurate?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, optimization, explain

I have the following table:

```
mysql> select count(*) from employees;  
+----------+  
| count(*) |  
+----------+  
|    10000 |  
+----------+  
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

I do an `EXPLAIN`: 
mysql> explain select last_name from employees order by last_name;

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+  
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+  
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9894 | Using filesort |  
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The rows are 9894. I was expecting 10000.
I do:

```
mysql> analyze table employees;
+-------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+  
| Table                               | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |  
+-------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+  
| sql_dummy.employees | analyze | status   | OK       |  
+-------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------+  
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

and re-run `EXPLAIN`:

mysql> explain select last_name from employees order by last_name;

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra          |  
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10031 | Using filesort |  
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The rows are now 10031.

Does anyone know why the rows is never 10000? I have noticed this in other cases as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this surprising but that's the behavior of InnoDB.

The InnoDB storage engine does cardinality approximation by walking a few levels down the nonleaf BTREE nodes and takes an educated guess.

I wrote about this a long time ago based on [**mysqlperformanceblog.com**](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/)

- `Jun 21, 2011` : [From where does the MySQL Query Optimizer read index statistics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics/3402#3402)
- `Aug 03, 2011` : [When should I rebuild indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/when-should-i-rebuild-indexes/4285#4285)
- `Feb 23, 2013` : [How does mysql deal with queries that touches myisam and innodb tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35322/how-does-mysql-deal-with-queries-that-touches-myisam-and-innodb-tables/35323#35323)

Perhaps you could try disabling that behavior by running this:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0;
```

Setting [**innodb_stats_on_metadata**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata)  should stabilize the approximate cardinality and you should get the same cardinality over and over again.

Comment: Do they do this for some kind of performance reasons?It seems easy to me to keep a counter for the leaf nodes of the b-tree

Comment: BTW if you have some time to spare http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by :)

Comment: @Cratylus Keeping a real count on a transaction based engine like innodb its very very hard   because of the row level locking and rollbacks that should be happen on the same time because innodb is more multithreaded engine and calculations on multiple threads is hard to pull off correctly thats probably the reason why it's a estimate value

Comment: Makes sense now