# Strange things with Avg_row_length

Tags: mysql, innodb, statistics

The data from one tables is dumped to file and inserted into `calls_old` table with `load data infile` it shows `Avg_row_length 7366`.

Later I dumped table with mysqldump, droped table, then created again and imported data. Now Avg_row_length is 471.

```
| Name       | Engine | Rows     | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Index_length | Data_free  |
+------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-

          before
| calls_old  | InnoDB |  1185666 |           7366 |  8733835264 |   4875419648 | 5329911808 |     

         after

| calls_old  | InnoDB |  1277654 |            471 |   601882624 |    464175104 |    4194304
```

What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct conditions you need to be aware of

## CONDITION #1 : Fragmentation

It is obvious the table has experienced lots of INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs (or non-SELECT [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language)). Even loading data sorted by PRIMARY KEY order will make index pages lopsided, at least 45% sparse.

I have posts about this phenomenon before

- `Aug 03, 2011` : [When should I rebuild indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/when-should-i-rebuild-indexes/4285#4285)
- `Nov 26, 2012` : [Does the Int type primary key insert order affect query performance in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29282/does-the-int-type-primary-key-insert-order-affect-query-performance-in-mysql/29304#29304)
- `Oct 26, 2012` : [How badly does innodb fragment in the face of somewhat out-of-order insertions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27678/how-badly-does-innodb-fragment-in-the-face-of-somewhat-out-of-order-insertions/27685#27685) (I discuss AVL Trees Here)

Thus, data pages shrinking from 8733835264 (8.13G) to 601882624 (574M) and shrinking index pages from 4875419648 (4.54G) to (~443M) is not alarming. This will improve read performance.

## CONDITION #2 : InnoDB Row Count

InnoDB is notorious for [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) having spurious counts. MyISAM tables give accurate row counts in the table_rows column of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

InnoDB likes to do dives into the index pages in order to guess the number the rows in the table.

I have discussed this feature before as well

- `Feb 23, 2013` : [How does mysql deal with queries that touches myisam and innodb tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35322/how-does-mysql-deal-with-queries-that-touches-myisam-and-innodb-tables/35323#35323) (See ASPECT #3)
- `Aug 04, 2011` : [Optimizing InnoDB default settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/optimizing-innodb-default-settings/4325#4325)
- `Jun 21, 2011` : [From where does the MySQL Query Optimizer read index statistics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics/3402#3402)

If you want an accurate count of an InnoDB table, you must bite the bullet and run

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM calls_old;
```

which will produce the same count every time.

Running this:

```
SELECT table_rows FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'calls_old';
```

never gives you the same value each time.

In fact, if you run

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM calls_old;
```

look at the cardinality column. It will produce different numbers each time. You would have to lock it down by setting [innodb_stats_on_metadata](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata) to 0. Even if you did that, the stats would become stale over time through normal [non-SELECT DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) just like a MyISAM table. Running `ANALYZE TABLE calls_old` with [innodb_stats_on_metadata](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata) set to 0 will fix the index statistics.

Having [innodb_stats_on_metadata](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata) remain at 1 will make `ANALYZE TABLE calls_old`  completely useless. (See my post [From where does the MySQL Query Optimizer read index statistics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics/3402#3402)).

Since the table is called `calls_old`, I can surmise that you do not need to adjust any other options since it may be an archive table as the name suggests.

## EPILOGUE

The value of `Avg_row_length` is a good indicator that you should defragment the table. When you see an InnoDB table growing that much, you could just run

```
ALTER TABLE calls_old ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

to shrink that table.

Thus, the behavior you are seeing is driven by the two conditions I just discussed.

## SUGGESTION

If you want to verify the contents, you should these two queries:

- `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM calls_old;`
- `CHECKSUM TABLE calls_old`;

before and after dumping/importing.