# Need help to understand how information_schema.TABLES get updated

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, information-schema

I created large innodb table

```
mysql> select count(*) from big_data;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 23822336 |
+----------+
```

checked the stats in `informaion_schema.TABLES`

```
mysql> select data_length, index_length, data_free 
       from information_schema.TABLES 
       where TABLE_NAME = 'big_data';

+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| data_length | index_length | data_free |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
|  4385144832 |            0 |         0 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Then deleted approx 4M rows.

Checked the count

```
mysql> select count(*) from big_data;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 19978240 |
+----------+
```

checked the `information schema.TABLES`

```
mysql> select data_length, index_length, data_free 
       from information_schema.TABLES 
       where TABLE_NAME = 'big_data';

+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| data_length | index_length | data_free |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
|  4385144832 |            0 |         0 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

There is no change!!

Can somebody please explain to me what happened?

I'm using mysql 5.6.18

Answer (score 4):

InnoDB is telling you that the data pages are the same size.

The DELETE you ran simply makred the rows delete within the associated data pages.

You have to run

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE big_data;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE big_data ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

to shrink it.

Since you inserted data into a table with no indexes, that explains 0 for `index_length`.

The `data_free` column is really superfluous when [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) is 1 (Thta's the default for MySQL 5.6). The `data_free` column was used to give you the total space free inside ibdata1 when innodb_file_per_table = 0 and all data and indexes were inside ibdata1. Since [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) = 1 and you loaded data into MySQL from the its beginning, I believe 0 will always appear for `data_free` for every InnoDB table in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html).

Here is something else to consider: The [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) does not properly update because of the Storage Engine's ineraction with it.

For example, I noticed you used

```
select count(*) from big_data;
```

Why did you not use

```
select data_length, index_length, data_free, table_rows
from information_schema.TABLES 
where TABLE_NAME = 'big_data';
```

Using this Pictorial Representation of the InnoDB Architecture

## InnoDB Architecture

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

try imagine what is happening when you delete 4 million rows:

- Drag data pages for the 4M rows into the buffer pool
- Capture those rows in the Rollback Segments
- Mark the rows delete inside those memory-resident data pages
- Write the changes into the Double Write Buffer
- Migrate changed data pages through the Log Buffer to commit the changes back to the `.ibd` file
- Write Redo Log Info into the Transaction Logs (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1).
- Clean up the Rollback Segments upon the completion of the DELETE.

In light of this, it would take a considerable amount of time for the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) to catch up with all these changes.

Please note that you could never reliably extract exact row counts from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html). The MySQL Query Optimizer always approximates row counts for InnoDB tables by scanning non-leaf BTREE nodes. I have written about this consistently in the DBA StackExchange for almost 3 years.

- `Mar 03, 2014` : [The most efficient method to obtain the total entries into a mysql table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60053/the-most-efficient-method-to-obtain-the-total-entries-into-a-mysql-table/60065#60065)
- `Feb 23, 2013` : [How does mysql deal with queries that touches myisam and innodb tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35322/how-does-mysql-deal-with-queries-that-touches-myisam-and-innodb-tables/35323#35323) (See ASPECT #3)
- `Apr 23, 2012` : [Why is a secondary index chosen over a clustered index for SELECT COUNT(*) ...?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/why-is-a-secondary-index-chosen-over-a-clustered-index-for-select-count/16900#16900)
- `Aug 04, 2011` : [Optimizing InnoDB default settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/optimizing-innodb-default-settings/4325#4325)
- `Jun 21, 2011` : [From where does the MySQL Query Optimizer read index statistics?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics/3402#3402)

Therefore, it is not surprising that other metadata aspects of InnoDB do not update column info in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) effectively .

## What if the table was MyISAM ???

MyISAM does not have to jump through all these hoops like InnoDB. Notwithstanding, even if the `big_data` table was MyISAM, the `.MYD` file would remain the same size after the DELETE. You would still have to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE big_data;` to shrink the `.MYD`